# Android Layout question?

Tags: android

I want to have navigation bar at the bottom of my screen.
There will be 'Prev' button at rightest and a 'Next' button at leftest.
And a textview on center.

I tried linear and relative layout but failed.
When I put width="fill_parent" to text then left button dissappears.

Here the one I tried:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/rlayout"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
               <!-- other content a listview etc.
               -->

        <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/navigator"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
        <Button android:id="@+id/prevbtn"
                android:background="@drawable/prev"  android:onClick="prevPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pageText"
                android:text=""
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/nextbtn"
                android:background="@drawable/next"
                android:onClick="nextPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code changes will work:

1. For the textview change 'fill_parent' to 'wrap_content for both height and width.
2. For the buttons and the textview add `android:layout_weight="1"`.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/navigator"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/prevbtn"
        android:onClick="prevPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pageText"
        android:text=""
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/nextbtn"
        android:onClick="nextPage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Great thanks, I am near to success. Only problem is about the background images are wider than original losing their image ratio and quality. Will trying to fix it but if you know answer please help, thanks again.

Comment: I solved it. As 0 weight value for buttons, 1 weight value for textview.

Answer (score 0):

Try `alignParentLeft="true"` and `alignParentRight="true"` on the two buttons.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/rlayout"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
               <!-- other content a listview etc.
               -->

        <LinearLayout  android:id="@+id/navigator"
                      android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >
        <Button android:id="@+id/prevbtn"
                android:background="@drawable/prev"
                android:onClick="prevPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alignParentLeft="true" />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pageText"
                android:text=""
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                />
        <Button android:id="@+id/nextbtn"
                android:background="@drawable/next"
                android:onClick="nextPage"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:alignParentRight="true" />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried but sorry.. All are floated to left. So then I give fillparent to middle one this time left one dissappears.